# Checking for NaN or <= 0

Tags: javascript

Jshint is not pleased with this expression:

```
 var amount = $('.some-input').val()
 // Check for NaN or <= 0
 if (!(+amount > 0)) {
    ...
 }
```

It claims **confusing use of !**. Is there a way to rewrite the expression without adding too much code?

Comment: Well, `if (isNaN(amount) || +amount <= 0)`…

Comment: Or simply move the `+` before the `$`, allowing you to simplify the conditional. It also feels natural to me, as in "`amount` is the numeric value of ...".

Comment: Why do you think you would need to rewrite the expression? Jshint is wrong, it cannot see that it's properly comment-documented.

Comment: very good point, Jshint cannot see the comments

Comment: I don't understand your preoccupation with less code. If you write it out fully in the first place per Bergi's comment, no code comment is required and it's less to type than the shorter version with the comment.

Comment: The comment was intended for StackOverflow users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent without the negation is:

```
if (amount <= 0 || isNaN(amount)) {
```

So, instead of saying *"Is not greater than"*, you are saying *"Is less than or equal"*. Additionally, not everyone might know that `NaN` cannot really be compared to numbers (i.e. always returns `false`) and hence an explicit test can make this expression easier to read and understand overall.

Apparently humans find negations more difficult to understand and I would not say that there is no truth to it.

Comment: No. If you put `NaN` in here, the result is different. Logic is ternary :-)

Comment: @Bergi: True... maybe you should put your comment as an answer then, because it's the only correct one.

Comment: @PaulS.: Ah sure... I read "smaller or equal" as one "block" and "than" seemed to be fit better. Anyways, changed the order :)

Comment: @FelixKling fair reasoning.

Comment: @Bergi: I updated my answer, but I really feel that you should write your own. I would delete mine then.

Comment: FelixKling and @PaulS., you're both only partway there.  To be grammatically correct, it's either "smaller than or equal to" or "equal to or smaller than," but "equal or smaller than" is just as wrong as "smaller or equal than"! ;)

Comment: @Derek: Ok, to solve this once and for all I just used the terminology from the specification: http://es5.github.io/#x11.8.3 :D

Answer (score 2):

You could write

```
if (amount > 0 === false) {
```

The string is automatically converted to a number when in this comparison, and any string that can't be correctly parsed as a number is converted to `NaN` which isn't `>0`. And jshint seems to be pleased when it sees `=== false` in place of the convenient `!`.

But the real solution seems to **not** use jshint, which isn't pertinent here. This tool doesn't let you use the power of JavaScript.

If you decide to drop jshint, I'd still advise you to simplify a little your test as

```
if (!(amount > 0)) {
```

Quality wise, the most important here would be in my opinion the small comment you already added.

Comment: Not sure why jshint doesn't know to warn "*do not compare to booleans*" - I find that expression actually more confusing than the negation :-)

Comment: @Bergi I too. But that's not the first time I encounter this "quality" tool and I don't take it very seriously.

Comment: @Bergi I haven't heard that before, what's wrong with comparing _boolean_?

Comment: @paulS Do *you* prefer `if (cond===false)` over `if (!cond)` ?

Comment: @dystroy If I have a really big `cond` (not necessarily complicated), I sometimes do `if (false === cond)`

Comment: @PaulS: Comparing a boolean value against `true` is superfluous, and comparing one against `false` should better be written with a `NOT` operator.

Comment: @dystroy I think I probably use it because I'll sometimes write loops like `while (false !== expr)` (allowing for a `null`, `undefined` or something and wanting to continue), so I don't find seeing it formed like that so weird in an `if`.

Comment: @Paul: You are right, sometimes it *is* necessary to make explicit tests. But if it is not, one could argue it is inferior style. Anyways, in the end it's a matter of habit.